# Linux Can't Detect Wllan0

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, broadcom

I Can't Connect To `Wifi` When I Type `ifconfig` wlan0 up it shows `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device` i tried solutions like re-installing `firmware-b43-installer` , installing `wicd` downloading Broadcom packages But it Doesn't seem to work. I Have a Breadcom bcm43142 and when I Type `ifconfig` it shows

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:86:7a:62:4f:8a  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)
```

and the command `dmesg | tail` shows

```
[   17.455266] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   17.455269] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[  653.534672] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: IN
[  653.538524] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
[  653.538531] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
[  653.538534] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  653.538540] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  653.538544] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  653.538548] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  653.538552] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
```

if anyone have any idea how to solve this a would really appreciate it.
The `ip link` command show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:86:7a:62:4f:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:03:00:5a:33:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

usb0 is my phone am using it as usb modem

Comment: What does `ip link` show?

Comment: i added it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can check for:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -A2 Broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

You can then check for:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Then you can check for:

```
$ lsmod | grep wl
wl                   4207760  0 
cfg80211              480503  1 wl
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
```

While you are at it... do the following and get back to me:

```
$ uname -a
$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```